# Silverlight Preload Controls

Tags: silverlight, performance

Is there a way to get Silverlight databound controls to load in the background to shorten load times during another part of application use? Specifically, I have a tab control containing a datagrid that is slow to load when there are large number of columns and rows. The performance hit occurs the first time I click the tab. Is there a way to force this load on a background thread when app first opens or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is exactly relevant but I just resolved an issue I had where I was firing up a new grid (which was already loaded but not visible). In the process of making it visible I also assign the ItemSource of a datagrid inside which - via a converter - generates controls. What I found was that although the datagrid in silverlight typically only loads rows it needs to (based on visibility) in my case the code sequence to show the grid and bind was happening too quickly and because the grid wasn't yet shown it (silverlight) decided it needed to load all the rows.

Calling UpdateLayout() prior to generating the controls and binding resolved the issue.